# Play Scala Dependency injection: How to use it

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I am trying to use Play 2.5 dependency injection. I have following class which makes a call to REST api and parses the response

```
class Client @Inject()(ws:WSClient, baseUrl: string) {

  def this(ws:WSClient) = this(ws, "<url string>")
  def getResponse() = {....}
....

}
```

The caller of the code looks like below

```
var client = new Client(WS.client)
client.getResponse()
```

I am getting following warning.

> object WS in package ws is deprecated: Inject WSClient into your
>   component

I understand that i need to inject WS.Client instead of passing it explicitly to the Client constructor. But how do i do that?

**=== Update ===**

I don't want to inject Client or WSClient from the Controller. My controller creates objects and classes at run time and i want those objects to create Client Object. When i explicitly pass WS.client object to the Client object i get the above stated warning.

**=== Update 2 ===**

I have a plugin architecture in my application. When a a controller starts an action. It does not know what set of plugins it is going to execute. Some plugins would not need a WSClient and some of them would. So i dont want to couple the injection of WSClient into my controller. Each plugin independently decides if it wants to call a remote service. When a plugin decides to call the remote service, it should be able to inject WSClient in what ever client it wants to invoke.

Controller Action --> Determine Plugins to Execute --> Execute Plugins ---> Plugin1 (needs to call a remote api, create a client object, per say new Client(WS.Client)). This is where the injection should happen, not at the controller.

Comment: Show the code where the warning is appearing. Are you sure you are using the injected `WSClient` there instead of `WS`?

Comment: the warning is being shown on new Client(WS.client) line. My question is how to use use injected WSClient @marcospereira

Comment: Is this caller a test or other regular class in your project? Any reason to not use dependency injection to create and bind the `Client`?

Comment: @marcospereira, that is my question, how do i inject the dependency? i dont know how to do that, can you share the code. This is a class in my project.

Comment: Post the class where this warning happens.

Comment: Could you post some actual code?

Comment: Did you ever get a good solution to this? (marco's answer is interesting, but quite verbose...)

Answer (score 12):

Ok. I will assume you have two classes. First we will have your `Client` class:

```
@Singleton // this is not necessary, I put it here so you know this is possible
class Client @Inject() (ws:WSClient, baseUrl: String) {

    // Since this controller is not annotated with @Inject
    // it WILL NOT be used when binding components
    def this(ws:WSClient) = this(ws, "<url string>")

    def getResponse() = {
        // do something using ws object
    }
}
```

Then you have another class that uses `Client`, per instance, a controller:

```
class MyController @Inject() (client: Client) extends Controller {

    def someAction = Action {
        // do something with client object
    }

}
```

The main point here is that the controller did not need to create a `Client` instance. It was automatically injected by Guice.

Moreover, your client class needs a `baseUrl` and there is no place telling Play which value is needed there. If this is a configuration, than you can do something like this:

```
import play.api.Configuration

class Client @Inject() (ws:WSClient, configuration: Configuration) {

    def getResponse() = {
        val baseUrl = configuration.getString("key.to.baseUrl")
        // do something using ws object and baseUrl
    }
}
```

But, if you **really** want your `Client` object to receives a `String`, then we need to [tell Play which String needs to be injected](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings):

```
package com.acme.modules

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.google.inject.name.Names

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[String])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("baseUrl")) // attention to the name here. It will be used below
      .toInstance("http://api.example.com/")
  }
}
```

And then enable this module by adding the following line to your `application.conf`:

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.acme.modules.MyModule"
```

After that, we will change `Client` to be specific about which `String` it is expecting:

```
import play.api.Configuration

// @Named needs to receive the same value defined at the module class.
class Client @Inject() (ws:WSClient, @Named("baseUrl") baseUrl: String) {

    def getResponse() = {
        val baseUrl = configuration.getString("key.to.baseUrl")
        // do something using ws object and baseUrl
    }
}
```

### Update after question edit:

Give the structure you want/need:

```
Controller Action --> Determine Plugins to Execute --> Execute Plugins ---> Plugin1
```

Your code can also follow that path with classes like this:

```
MyController -> PluginResolver -> Plugin
             -> PluginRunner ->
```

And, then, you can have:

#### Controller:

```
class MyController @Inject() (
    pluginResolver: PluginResolver,
    pluginRunner: PluginRunner
) extends Controller {

    def action = Action {
        val plugins = pluginsResolver.resolve(/* give a criteria to select plugins */)
        val someResultFromPluginsExecution = pluginsRunner.run(plugins)

        // map result from plugins execution to a play play.api.mvc.Result
        // return the play.api.mvc.Result
    }
}
```

#### Plugin classes:

```
import play.api.inject.Injector

class PluginResolver @Inject()(injector: Injector) {

    def resolve(/* some criteria to resolve plugins */): Seq[Plugin] = {
        val pluginsClasses = ... // find the necessary plugins based on the criteria
        pluginsClasses.map { pluginClass => injector.instanceOf(pluginClass) }
    }

}

// ExecutionContext is not really necessary, but maybe you want/need
// another thread pool to execute plugins
class PluginRunner @Inject()(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

    def run(plugins: Seq[Plugin]): Seq[PluginExecutionResult] = {
        // run the plugins
        // return the result
    }
}

trait Plugin {
    def execute(): PluginExecutionResult
}
```

The real magic here happens at the `PluginResolver`. It uses a [`play.api.inject.Injector`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.inject.Injector) to create plugins instances and then your plugins can use Dependency Injection. Per instance:

```
class PluginThatNeedsWSClient @Inject(wsClient: WSClient) extends Plugin {
    def execute(): PluginExecutionResult = {
        // Use wsClient to call a remote service
        // return the execution result
    }
}
```

### Reference:

1. [Scala: Dependency Injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection)
2. [Scala: Play WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS)
3. [`play.api.inject.Injector`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.inject.Injector)

Comment: thanks, but i dont want to inject Client or WSClient from the controller. My app design dynamically decides which object gets created. I dont want to pass Client object from controller to every object that was created by my controller. Can i inject WSClient without injecting Client from controller?

Comment: You can adapt the explanation above to your use case. Just inject the WSClient where the Client object is created and, instead of `new Client(WS.client)`, do `new Client(myInjectedWSClient)`.

Comment: where would myInjectedWSClient be injected from? the controller? i dont want to inject any dependencies in the controller.

Comment: Why not? Moreover, is practically impossible to me to answer your question without knowing how your classes are structured. Where is the `Client` object being created? If it is being created at the controller, then you must inject `WSClient` at the controller.

Comment: I updated the question. My controller would endup creating objects. Inside these objects i want to create new Client and inject WSClient instance.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this awesome post last week: http://www.schibsted.pl/2016/04/dependency-injection-play-framework-scala/