# how to get current application instance in companion object

Tags: scala, playframework

Before play framework 2.5, i can get current application instance within an object, as following code:

```
  object MyObj {
      val app = Play.current
  }
```

But Play.current is deprecated from play 2.5, so how can i get current application instance from MyObj object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite `MyObj` to be a class and then inject the `Application`:

```
class MyObj @Inject() (currentApplication: Application) {
    ...
}
```

Play will then inject the application at your `MyObj`, which can be injected at other objects as well.

Here are some other discussions with examples and other aspects related to how to use Dependency Injection with Play:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36685623/4600
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36948125/4600

Comment: But i want keep MyObj as an object instead of a class. Even i change MyObj to a class, so how to instance it?

Comment: You don't instantiate it. Play and Guice will. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection

Comment: Sorry, i'm new on play framework. How to get an instance of an MyObj class in play? Give me an example, thank you.

Comment: It seems that i can't use injection in object. Because injection muse be a class.

Comment: @JackyChan exactly.